# Github Actions run Nunit Selenium tests question

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, github-actions, specflow

I have a Visual Studio Solution with 3 projects. These are the main web application project, a unit test project and finally at Selenium, NUnit, SpecFlow regression test project.

I am trying to setup CI/CD in GitHub actions and so far I have in my yaml file 2 jobs.

Job 1 runs the unit tests project against the web project and this passes

```
  tests:        
    name:  Unit Testing
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2.1.0
      - run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
```

Job 2 builds the web project

```
  build:
    name:  BuildProject
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 5.0.x
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
```

What I want to do now is add a third job, this job will run the selenium test suite against the main web project but I cannot figure out how to get this running from the yaml file.

Can anyone point me towards a good step through or example please.

Cheers

Kev

So now I have added this job

```
regression:  
needs: tests 
name: Regression tests   
runs-on: windows-latest
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2.1.0
  - run: dotnet test SpiceTheWorld.Regression --no-restore --verbosity normal
```

This appears to run with no errors but it completes in 20 seconds, running the same on command line takes 40 seconds so I am not sure it is actually running.

This is the output

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What errors have you encountered? Have you checked this out: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Getting-Started/Getting-Started-With-An-Example.html#further-dotnet-test-examples?

Comment: No, that is the regression project name within the solution

Comment: dotnet test SpiceTheWorld.Regression --no-build --verbosity normal --filter TestCategory=SpiceRegression works fine on command line

Comment: Run it with detailed verbosity and post the complete log of the step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help.
I have it working now, below is the script.

```
    name: Spicethedeploy
on:
  push:
    branches: [ development ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ development ]
    
jobs:
  
  build:
    name:  Buildspice
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core SDK ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.7.2
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
      
  unittests:      
    needs: build
    name:  Unit Testing
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core SDK ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.7.2
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Unit Tests
      run: dotnet test SpiceTheWorld.Tests --no-restore --verbosity Minimal          
 
  regression:  
    needs: unittests 
    name: Regression
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core SDK ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.7.2
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Regression tests 
      run: dotnet test SpiceTheWorld.Regression --no-restore --verbosity Minimal --filter TestCategory=SpiceRegression
```

[image]

[image]